# Determine which guest is running on XEN: HVM or PV guest

Tags: linux, xen, centos5, xenserver

I'm working with a Xen host which is installed XenServer from Citrix by someone. He already installed a lot of CentOS 5.2 guests on the host. I wonder how to check those guests to know they are PV types or HVM types?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A quick note, there are actually 3 modes, not two when it comes to the drivers in use:

- HVM: unmodified kernel and drivers using software emulated devices
- PV-HVM: unmodified kernel with paravirtualized (Xen specific) disk
  and network drivers
- PV: modified kernel and drivers

For a Xen guest/DomU you can do a very basic `uname` and `lsmod` with a grep to list the modules in use:

```
uname -a
lsmod | grep xen
```

If `uname -a` lists a kernel with the string "xen" in it, then you have a modified kernel and it's likely a PV guest, and you will see output from the `lsmod` command to confirm it.  If you have output from the grep on `lsmod` but no sign of a modified kernel then you are PV-HVM.  Without any sign of either, it's a straight HVM.

Note: Generally you can do more with VMs that have the PV tools installed, so that can be quite an obvious pointer, however you can [fake the presence](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/XAPI_fake_presence_of_PV_drivers) of the PV tools to allow suspend/resume etc. so you cannot rely on that in general.

Comment: Thanks @Adam. It's the clearest answer that I have found so far.

Answer (score 13):

There is a better alternative to analyzing `uname -a` output from inside the guest domain. You should rather check the VM profile in the hypervisor itself.

### XL

With *the current* XenLight toolstack for standalone Xen installations, this could be achieved by running `xl list --long` command:

```
# xl list
Name                   ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
My-Virtual-Machine     42  1024     1     -b----    9001.0

# xl list -l 42
    or
# xl list --long My-Virtual-Machine

[
    {
        "domid": 6,
        "config": {
            "c_info": {
                "name": "My-Virtual-Machine",
                "uuid": "12345678-abcd-1234-abcd-12345678abcd",
                "type": "pv",
                ...
            },
            ...
        }
    }
]
```

Note the `type` item in the `c_info` section — if it equals `"pv"`, this means paravirtual.

### XM

With *an older* standalone Xen installation using traditional `xm` management toolstack, things were similar:

```
# xm list --long My-Virtual-Machine
(domain
    (domid 42)
    (name My-Virtual-Machine)
    (image
        (linux
            (kernel ...)
            ...
        )
    )
    ...
)
```

Note the `(linux)` element in the `(image)` section — it corresponds to the `builder` configuration directive, where “linux” means “paravirtual” (rather than the actual kernel), while “hvm” stands for “full virtualization”.

### XE

With XenServer or XCP *appliance* you could use `xe vm-list params=all` command or something alike.

### virsh

There may be (or have been) some way to get this information from *libvirt* toolstack, but unknown to me.

---

Note that, starting with Xen 4.5, paravirtual mode on x86-64 has two flavors:

- *classic paravirtualization* (PV) that relies on guest systems to be rewritten from using [ring 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring) towards ring 1; since AMD has thrown away ring 1 and ring 2 in x86-64, Xen had to fall back to software-based management, which is even slower than HVM;
- *hardware-assisted paravirtualization* (PVH), — not to be confused with *fully virtualized with paravirtual drivers* (PV-on-HVM), — that relies on hardware assistance for handling privileged instructions and memory page tables, but uses traditional PV techniques for everything else, so that no hardware is emulated and near-native performance is achieved as it was in good old x86-32 times.

To check whether the host runs with PVH enabled, one may use `xl info` (although this method is no better than inspecting *grub.cfg*):

```
# xl info | grep xen_commandline
xen_commandline        : pvh=1 loglvl=all guest_loglvl=all console=com1,vga
                         ^^^^^
```

To check whether particular guest is running in PVH mode (`pvh=1` in configuration file), again, consult `xl list -l`:

```
            "c_info":{
                "name": "My-Virtual-Machine",
                "type": "pv",
                "pvh": "True",
                ...
            },
```

However, from the administration perspective, PVH should not be any different to PV.

Comment: This does not works on 4.4.1 because there is no `xm` command but `xl` which has different output. Any idea how to get the info on 4.4.1 XEN. Thanks.

Comment: @WakanTanka I don't currently have access to a working Xen server, but according to the sample output found online the approach is basically the same. See the updated answer.

Comment: This is a far better approach then @AdamC's answer, because I have several PV ubuntu guests that are definitely PV according to `xl`, and yet have no mention of xen in the kernel name or kernel modules.

Comment: This requires access to the hypervisor, how can one know if (s)he only has access to the guest?